# how to output awk result to varial

Tags: shell, awk

i need to run hadoop command to list all live nodes, then based on the output i reformat it using awk command, and eventually output the result to a variable, awk use different delimiter each time i call it:

```
hadoop job -list-active-trackers | sort | awk -F. '{print $1}' | awk -F_ '{print $2}'
```

it outputs result like this:

```
hadoop-dn-11
hadoop-dn-12
...
```

then i put the whole command in variable to print out the result line by line:

```
var=$(sudo -H -u hadoop bash -c "hadoop job -list-active-trackers | sort | awk -F "." '{print $1}' | awk -F "_" '{print $2}'")

printf %s "$var" | while IFS= read -r line
    do
        echo "$line"
    done
```

the awk -F didnt' work, it output result as:

```
tracker_hadoop-dn-1.xx.xsy.interanl:localhost/127.0.0.1:9990
tracker_hadoop-dn-1.xx.xsy.interanl:localhost/127.0.0.1:9390
```

why the awk with -F won't work correctly? and how i can fix it?

Comment: I suspect the `sudo -H -u hadoop bash -c ...` is having a lot more effect that storing the result in a variable is. Have you tried running `sudo -H -u hadoop bash -c "hadoop job -list-active-trackers | sort | awk -F "." '{print $1}' | awk -F "_" '{print $2}'"` and if so does that produce the output you expect? Pay particular attention to `"hadoop job -list-active-trackers | sort | awk -F "` - that is a matched pair of double quotes on either end of that string and so the 2nd one will terminate the string started by the first one.

Comment: @Ed: i tried what you mentioned, still won't work...

Comment: Right so your problem has nothing to do with the subject of your question `how to output awk result to varial` so fix that and reduce your problem to the smallest code segment that can reproduce the problem and you'll see what the cause of the problem is. Looks like @glennjackman figured it out for you already though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var=$(sudo -H -u hadoop bash -c "hadoop job -list-active-trackers | sort | awk -F "." '{print $1}' | awk -F "_" '{print $2}'")
```

Because you're enclosing the whole command in double quotes, your shell is expanding the variables `$1` and `$2` before launching sudo. This is what the sudo command looks like (I'm assuming $1 and $2 are empty)

```
sudo -H -u hadoop bash -c "hadoop job -list-active-trackers | sort | awk -F . '{print }' | awk -F _ '{print }'"
```

So, you see your awk commands are printing the whole line instead of just the first and 2nd fields respectively.

This is merely a quoting challenge

```
var=$(sudo -H -u hadoop bash -c 'hadoop job -list-active-trackers | sort | awk -F "." '\''{print $1}'\'' | awk -F "_" '\''{print $2}'\')
```

A bash single quoted string cannot contain single quotes, so that's why you see `...'\''...` -- to close the string, concatenate a literal single quote, then re-open the string.

Another way is to escape the vars and inner double quotes:

```
var=$(sudo -H -u hadoop bash -c "hadoop job -list-active-trackers | sort | awk -F \".\" '{print \$1}' | awk -F \"_\" '{print \$2}'")
```

Comment: thanks!  i tried the second approach, and it worked!